# QComboBox display default

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I have created a QComboBox using the following:

```
Drop = QtGui.QComboBox()
[Drop.addItem(i) for i in [cat,dog,mouse, llama]]
```

I want the QComboBox to display 'mouse' instead of 'cat' when I start the GUI without changing the order in the list. 'mouse' should be my default option and I want my user to know that.

Answer (score 0):

The following line does the trick:

```
Drop.setCurrentIndex(2)
```